# How to implement a multiple-owners document in Angularfire?

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire

I'm designing an Angular application with Firebase, where a certain document (shop) can be owned by multiple owners (users), and also an owner can own multiple shops! (many to many relationship)

If I store the owners uid as an array inside the shop document, it's going to be hard in Angular to query for documents where I'm one of the owners.

Alternatively, many have advised that I store their uid's in a map, like this:

```
shop = {
  name: string,
  owners: {
    id1: id1,
    id2: id2,
    ...etc
  }
}
```

and then query like:

```
.where('owners.'+myUid, '==', myUid)
```

This works like a charm, except for when I'm trying to order the list of shops by name alphabetically while querying.

Once I add [orderBy], it complains that it needs to create an Index, but the problem is that it wants to create an index including my uid and name, which means an index for every user (which is not practical)!

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this particular query, you're going to need a different way to store your owners.  You could simply store the owners as an array of strings instead of a map, then query it with [array-contains](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#array_membership):

```
collection
    .where('owners', 'array-contains', myUid)
    .orderBy('name')
```

Comment: Great, then how would I allow only owners of a certain shop to read and write to it? (from security rules point of view)

Comment: It sounds like you have a new question.  Please post that separately showing the rules you have that aren't working the way you expect.